# Check if object has relation with other in ManyToMany field and aggregate field

Tags: python, django

I have a couple models as follows:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Class, related_name="students")

class Class(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField
```

What I need is a way such that, when querying students in certain class, instead of just returnig the students enrolled in that class, it returns a QuerySet of all the students, each one with an aggregated field indicating if such student is enrolled in that class, e.g.:

```py
[{'name':'student A', 'enrolled_in_physics':True}, {'name':'student B', 'enrolled_in_physics':False}]
```

I think it can be achieved through `F() expressions` along with `ExpressionWrapper`, but have no idea of how implement them; additionaly, the documentation and the examples are not very noob-friendly. Any help is appreciated, thanks!.

**EDIT**: Ok, I think using the word "*list*" is not the correct one, I need a normal **QuerySet**, such that let me do something like this:

```py
student_a = query[0]
student_a.name
>>>'A'
student_a.enrolled_in_physics
>>>True
```

Comment: Where do you want to initiate this process? Do you want this to all students and get the enrollment for a single class?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
You could try defining a method within the student class:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Class, related_name="students")

    def enrolled_in_class(self,class_name):
        if len(Class.objects.filter(nombre=class_name,students__in=self)) > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

students = Student.objects.all()
student_a = students[0]
student_a.name
student_a.enrolled_in_class('physics')
```

---

*Original Answer:*

**Edit:** Sorry misread question, I'll try and get an answer together for what you actually wanted: A list of all students, and binary true false if they are enrolled in a specific class.

Alright, I'm reading this as a: 
I need a query that returns a list of dictionaries, indicating the student, and enrollment in a class.

```
#Assume: class_name = 'physics'
def get_class_list(class_name):
    filtered_class = Class.object.get(nombre=class_name)
    student_names = Students.objects.filter(classes__contains=filtered_class).values_list('name',flat=True)
    class_list = []
    for name in student_names:
        class_list = {}
        class_list['name'] = name
        enrolled_class_string = 'enrolled_in_' + class_name 
        class_list[enrolled_class_string] = True

    return class_list
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries with the keys named 'name', and 'class__name'

Comment: Ok, that works, but is no useful at all because I didn't describe correctly the problem (my bad). Need a normal QuerySet rather than a list, because need to work with the Student object. Thanks anyway!